# Workflow not triggered when data is being copied and pasted to the SP List

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I have an excel sheet that I am copying to Sharepoint list I have a workflow that triggers when you add a new item to the Sharepoint list. However, when I copy the details from the Excel sheet to the list the workflow is not triggered please help me find an alternative for the same.

Comment: Are you using Sharepoint\System account?

Comment: Yes, I have limited access is it because of this reason the workflow is not getting triggered

Comment: Sharepoint version?